# Setting CSS top percent not working as expected

Tags: css

I tried a responsive css layout,but "top:50%" can't work and the "left:50%" can.
Why it happened?

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0%;left:0%;height:100%;width:100%">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you specified a height for the parent container of the first div? ie body?

Comment: The left is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/8b9Lny2a/ what browser are you using.

Comment: Sorry,the parent div's height&width is 100%.It seemed about the 100% of the height doesn't work;But if I set parent div 1000px which is specified,the child div's top will be specified too...I want the child div'top responsive to its parent's height? Is that possible?

Comment: 100% on height will work if the parent element has a height set and it's not using a percent. The only way it would ever work is if the parents all the way to the `html` and `body` are set to 100% as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define a dimension for the parent container, e.g. div:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid red;position:relative;top:0%;left:0%;height:200px;width:300px">
    <div style="border: 2px solid green;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;height:50%;width:50%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Or

Another way is to just stretch the parent container, i.e. div, by its top, bottom, left, and right properties. Like this:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid red;position: absolute;top: 0px;bottom: 0px;left:0px;right:0px;">
    <div style="border: 2px solid green;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;height:50%;width:50%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider your original HTML:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;top:0%;left:0%;height:100%;width:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;">test</div>
</div>
```

The inner/child `div` has `position: absolute`, so it is out of the content flow of the parent element and will not contribute to the height or width of the parent element.

The parent `div` is in the content flow, but has no content, so its intrinsic
height would be zero. However, you specified `height: 100%`, but this will not do anything because the `div` has no height reference on which to base a computed value. So the computed height value for the parent `div` is zero.

As a result, the child element's `top` offset computes to `50%` of zero,
so it is positioned at the top edge of the parent block.

You would need either to specify a height for the parent `div` or assign

```
html, body {height: 100%}
```

as this would allow the `div` to compute its height based on the height of the
`body`, which is based on the height of the `html`, which being 100%, takes that of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

See the link below. I believe you're going to have a better result with Fixed for what it is you're trying to do, although I'm still not 100% sure I understand what that is.

http://jsfiddle.net/8q107wvb/1/

```
body {background:#e9e9e9; color:#202020;}
#wrapper {width:500px; background:#fff; margin:50% auto;}
.centered-content {position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; background:#fff; padding:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another to solve this issue

```css
* {
  height: 100%;
}
.first{  
  position:relative;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;height:100%;
  width:100%"
}
div{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div style=>Check this</div>
</div>
```