# IE setting "top" to a percentage value not working for an absolutely positioned element inside table-cell

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've tried the following and it's working well in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari. I couldn't get it to work with IE though, am I missing something?
http://jsfiddle.net/amrn/qn0dwohn/

inside `.centered` the `left` property is working properly, but it seems to be ignoring `top`.

(I'm using `table` and `table-cell` because I want the height of `.right` to be automatically the same as `.left`).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
}

.left {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.right {
  background-color: teal;
  position: relative;
}

.centered {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="centered"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it by using an extra nested `div` which is absolutely positioned in relation to the relatively positioned `table` (not the `table-cell`). http://jsfiddle.net/amrn/qn0dwohn/17/

The downside is that I have to explicitly set the `width` on that extra `div` to be the same as its parent.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
}

.left {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.right {
  background-color: teal;
}

.right-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.centered {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-wrapper">
      <div class="centered"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of ways to handle this.

***UPDATED***

Because IE seems to have an issue with absolute positioning while using table cells you can add another nested `div` that uses `display: block;` You [can see the js.fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qn0dwohn/15/).

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="nest">
        <div class="centered"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.nest {
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
```

The second method would be to not use `display: table-cell` and instead use `display: inline-block` Like this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.left, .right {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  background-color: orange;
}

.right {
  background-color: teal;
}

.centered {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

You can [see this working in your Js.Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qn0dwohn/9/).

Or lastly you could do the easiest fix which would be to add height to your HTML and BODY which will give your table a height of something greater than 0 since no content exists in it. You can [see a similar SO question here about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238042/setting-css-top-percent-not-working-as-expected).

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't use `inline-block` because I don't want to set the height explicitly for the second `div`. Using `top: 0` with `margin-top: 50%` worked well for me, any reason why I should create an IE only stylesheet? won't it work with other browsers?

Comment: @AmrNoman if you follow the instructions using the link I supplied for the IE only CSS file it will not effect any of the other web browsers. In that CSS file you will only put the CSS changes you need to address the issues in IE.

Comment: I'm sorry, turns out using `top: 0` with `margin-top: 50%` doesn't work. It's calculating 50% of the child's height, whereas `top: 50%` calculates 50% of the parent's height. so they're not the same thing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AmrNoman ahh you are correct. Adding the html and body height to 100% did not help?

Comment: Thanks for your help crazymatt, I used the extra `div` but making it `block` and positioning it relatively doesn't work. I had to make it `absolute` and set `position: relative` on the table itself. and then stretch it using `top: 0; bottom: 0;`. Please see my answer.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!