# Absolute positioned element - Top percentage not working

Tags: html, css, css-position

What could be the cause for an absolute positioned element to ignore a percentage for the "top" position? Percentages are working for "left", and I can use pixels and vh to position it vertically, just not a percentage.

Comment: You might have an invisible fixed element on the way or something. Can we see the code please?

Comment: without any code showing your issue, hard to guess :)

Comment: Here's something that you may find pertinent to resolving the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238042/setting-css-top-percent-not-working-as-expected

Comment: post code otherwise it's hard telling

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have to make the parent of the absolute element - "position: relative". So then the absolute element's top and left fields will get the applied values relative to parent.

Comment: Not the parent. The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a layout to its parent element.

Layout could be other than 'static' like 'fixed', 'absolute', 'relative'

This will help browser to understand that calculations of percentage need to be done in realtion to its parent and not the window size.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there are multiple ways to absolutely position an element.  Here is one way without using a parent DIV:

CSS:

```
   html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
   }
    .centered-axis-xy {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

} 
div.cyan5050 {
    width:50%;height:50%;
    background:cyan;
}
div p {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    margin-top: 20vh;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cyan5050 centered-axis-xy">
        <p>Content to Display</p>
</div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu7vptn7/57/)

Normally, if you use percentages one needs to provide a basis for the percentages of the DIV tag, namely  the height and width percentages of a containing outer DIV or else with respect to the html and body elements.  But, in this case, since the CSS incorporates a responsive positioning technique mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-element-in-div/23384995#23384995), the percentages for the html and body elements are optional thanks to the CSS transform being equipped with a translate() [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate).