# How to use percent in margin positioning to create bowser, device and screen width compatibility?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an element in my footer for mobile. This works when I use `px`, but when I try to use percent, it doesn't move. The reason I want to use percent is that it seems to go some way in positing an element absolutely across different devices/browsers, whereas `px`simply defines the margin in a single device/browser. So the question is, why won't `top: 10%` work when `top: 40px` does?

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
{.copyright{position: 
relative; 
transform:rotate(90deg); 
right: 150px; top: 10% 
!important; vertical-align: 
middle;}} 

<div  
class="copyright">copyr
ight</div>
```

Comment: When you think of it, when you say `10%`, it's a relative unit to... what? If you want it to be 10% of the viewport height, then use `10vh` for example.

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238042/setting-css-top-percent-not-working-as-expected ?

Comment: if you want to use `right`, `top`, `bottom` or `left` attributes the position has to be `absolute`

Comment: I can use `top: with position: relative;` no? Or do you mean if i want to use percent with top, bottom etc I'd need to set position to absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are calculated relative to the width of the parent element, even for the top and bottom margins.

For top and bottom margins, it is better to use the vh unit (viewport height).

1vh = 1/100 of the height of the viewport

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in testing `vh` seems to work a bit like `px`, it sets the viewport relative to specific device /browser but doesn't establish cross browser/device compatibility as footer placing also changes according to device /browser...

Comment: So, for it to work cross device/browser, it would need to set vh relative to footer and device and browser it seems, which somehow percent can do....the issue is also, sometimes percent works, sometimes it doesn't and why that is...